# event listener not working in angular( can't understand a line of code)

Tags: angular

I know vue. Everything seems to be similar in vue with angular.In HTML template I see the following event listener:

```
(mousedown)="mouseDown(); false;"
```

what is the purpose of false here?

Answer (score 0):

this is the equivalent of calling `event.preventDefault()`; just shorter